# CSS: video centered and resized between header and footer

Tags: html, css, video.js, live-streaming

I'm having difficulty in centering and resizing video.js in the page, I would like to set responsive size and never exceed the boundaries of the headers and footers, in any case, within them.

This is my starting point, basically i need to put a video instead the black square more big is possible, but not exeed header and footer boudaries, the best would be to obtain the video.js control bar axact over the footer with same width.
is there anyone who can help me get a good solution?
Thanks a lot!

[image]

**html:**

```
                <!doctype html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>title</title>
            <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/dist/dash.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-dash/releases/download/v2.9.1/videojs-dash.min.js"></script>

                <style type="text/css">

           .video-js .vjs-current-time { display: none; }
           .video-js .vjs-time-divider { display: none; }
           .video-js .vjs-duration { display: none; }
           .video-js .vjs-progress-control { display: none; }
           .video-js .vjs-remaining-time { display: none; right: auto;} 

                 body,html{
                    margin:0;
                    padding: 0;
                    background-color: white;
                }   

                * {
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }       

                .head {
                     position: relative;
                    display: block;
                    padding: 8px;
                    float: left;
                }
                .head:after {
                    content: "";
                    display: table;
                    clear: both;
                }   
                .left {
                width: 75%;
                background-color: #FF5A00;
                }

                .right {
                    width: 25%;
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                }

                    img {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }   

                .cent
                {

                    height:50px;
                    width:50px;
                    background-color:black;
                    margin:auto;
                    position:absolute;
                    left:50%;
                    top:50%;
                    margin-left:-25px;
                    margin-top:-25px;
                }

                    .footer {
                  position: absolute;
                  right: 0;
                  bottom: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  padding: 1rem;
                  background-color: #efefef;
                  text-align: center;
                        font-family: 'titles', Fallback, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 100%;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    letter-spacing: 1px;
                }
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div header="head">
                  <div class="head left">
                <img src="logos.png" alt="logo" height="20">
                  </div>
                <div class="head right">
                <img src="logos.png" alt="logo" height="20">
                  </div></header>
                <div class="cent">
        <video id=tv-video class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin vjs-show-big-play-button-on-pause vjs-big-play-centered" controls autoplay preload="auto"></video>
          <script>
          var player = videojs('tv-video');
          player.src({ src: 'video/manifest.mpd', type: 'application/dash+xml'});
          player.play();
              player.on("pause", function () {
                player.one("play", function () {
                  player.src({"type":player.currentType(), "src":player.currentSrc()});
                  player.play();
                });
              });
        </script>
        </div>
                <footer class="footer"><img src="firma.png" alt="logo" height="20"></footer>

                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: The video to show is 16:9

Comment: Is your goal to have a fullscreen (by that I mean non-scrolling) web page so that the header is always at the top, the footer always at the bottom, and the video takes up the remaining space? (Also, off topic, but: what is that font, if I may ask?)

Comment: yes! with player controls above footer, and never scrollbar

Comment: @chriskirknielsen is draw with flash, i take ispiration from bionic systems fonts, and TDR the designer republic stuff

Comment: http://www.bionic-systems.com/archive/portfolio2001/downloads/fonts.pdf

Comment: I have posted an answer that should get you the desired result. And thank you for sharing that about the fonts, it looks very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Notes

First off, note that your source code has errors, notably your header tag. I have fixed them in the code below, among other various improvements.

I only kept the contents of the `<body>` tag since this is the interesting part, and I cannot use your JavaScript as it is linking toward local resources. You can manipulate the code at your leisure afterwards to make it work like you want, as I cannot predict how video.js will work.

## Improvements

The `body` now has a `display: flex;` value to harness the power of flexbox. This allows you to have a flexible system where the header and footer stay in the same position (top and bottom) at the same size, no matter the screen size.

The header now uses the `<header>` tag, analogous to how `<footer>` is used for the footer. Is also uses a `display: flex;` to avoid using `float` on your elements.

The content has a `<main>` tag for semantic reasons, but I kept your `.cent` classname, which has some flex-related CSS: `flex` to take up space, and `align-self` to dictate how to behave in the flex context of the `body` (although the latter is not necessary - it works without -, it is there as a precaution).

The video is simply put to take up 100% of the `width` and `height` available.

As you can imagine, you cannot force a screen to show something in 16:9 if it isn't in that ratio. The default behaviour for `<video>` is then to scale down the video proportionally, so if you have a 16:9 ratio video file, it will play in 16:9 but there might be black bars on either the vertical or horizontal sides.

## Code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
}

.head {
  padding: 8px;
}

.left {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #FF5A00;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cent {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: black;
}

.video-js {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'titles', Fallback, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Content of the <body> tag -->
<header class="header">
  <div class="head left">
    <img src="logos.png" alt="logo" height="20">
  </div>
  <div class="head right">
    <img src="logos.png" alt="logo" height="20">
  </div>
</header>

<main class="cent">
  <video id="tv-video" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin vjs-show-big-play-button-on-pause vjs-big-play-centered" controls autoplay preload="auto"></video>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <img src="firma.png" alt="logo" height="20">
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I imagined there are many mistakes,  tried, but tu enlarge the page, the video invades the header, now the video end with the footer (before it may become bigger with scrollbar), but there still is the scrollbar.

Comment: i include two js files:
<script src="http://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/dist/dash.all.min.js"></script>

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what exactly is happening for you. If you run the above code snippet and put it in full page, no scrollbar should show.

Comment: Thanks chris that's are many steps forward, you are right, with full page no scroll bar, all fine, but if i play to resize windows in safari and chrome the video invade the header, could you notice?

Comment: I have updated my solution to correct what I believe to be the issue by positioning the video absolutely inside its container. Let me know how that works out for you across browsers (all good on Chrome, Safari and Firefox for me).

Comment: Thanks mate! same beahviour of amazon prime video